# Where is the flaw in my linear algorithm to

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Given a node like

```
class Node
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in descendant nodes
    /// </summary>   
    public int DescendantsSum { get; set; } = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in tree whose root is this node
    /// </summary>
    public int TreeSum { get { return Val + DescendantsSum; } }
}
```

and a tree of `Node`s with `Val`s that have been set, what I'm trying to do is what is described in the summary of the following method I wrote

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a tree like 
/// 
///       Val=100
///           \
///         Val=200
///           /   \
///          /     Val=100
///      Val=100
///     /       \
///   Val=500    Val=600
///
/// set a field for each node showing the sum of the values
/// in the subtree whose root is that node, making it into
/// 
///       Val=100
///       Sum=1600
///           \
///         Val=200
///         Sum=1500
///          /   \
///         /     Val=100
///        /      Sum=100
///      Val=100
///      Sum=1200
///     /        \
///   Val=500    Val=600
///   Sum=500    Sum=600
///   
/// </summary>
static void SetSums(Node[] nodes)
{
    foreach(var leaf in nodes.Where(node => node.Children.Count == 0))
        for(var cur = leaf; cur.Parent != null; cur = cur.Parent)
            cur.Parent.DescendantsSum += cur.TreeSum;
}
```

However, this is leading to incorrectly large values like `3400` where it should be `1600`. I've thought over my algorithm and I can't see where it is flawed. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to discuss the top-down vs bottom-up algorithms. You have chosen the bottom-up, fine, so where is the flaw?

Consider the following simple tree:

```
child1
      \
       parent - grandparent
      /
child2
```

Your algorithm will do:

```
parent.DescendantsSum += child1.TreeSum;
grandparent.DescendantsSum += parent.TreeSum;
parent.DescendantsSum += child2.TreeSum;
grandparent.DescendantsSum += parent.TreeSum;
```

As you can see, `parent.TreeSum` is added twice to the `grandparent.DescendantsSum` which leads to the incorrect results.

Since the `DescendantsSum` is effectively the sum of the `Val` of all descendant nodes, one way to fix the algorithm is to process all nodes and add the node `Val` to each node parent.

```
static void SetSums(Node[] nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
        node.DescendantsSum = 0;

    foreach (var node in nodes)
        for (var parent = node.Parent; parent != null; parent = parent.Parent)
            parent.DescendantsSum += node.Val;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with trees it's sometimes easier to go from the top to the buttom and not the other way as you did.

I think this should work for your needs:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in descendant nodes
    /// </summary>   
    public int DescendantsSum 
    { 
        get 
        {
            var sum = 0;
            foreach(var child in Children)
            {
                sum += child.TreeSum;

                //You can do this instead
                //sum += child.Val;
                //sum += child.DescendantsSum; 
            }
            return sum;
        } 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sum of values in tree whose root is this node
    /// </summary>
    public int TreeSum { get { return Val + DescendantsSum; } }
}
```

Or by using LINQ:

```
public int DescendantsSum 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return Children.Sum(child => child.TreeSum);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Totally agree... Top to bottom makes more sense and the SetSums method that takes an array of Nodes as parameter is totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function.
This works fine:

```
class NodeTest
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            var root = new Node() { Val = 1 };

            var a1 = new Node() { Val = 2 };
            var a2 = new Node() { Val = 3 };

            var a11 = new Node() { Val = 4 };
            var a12 = new Node() { Val = 5 };
            var a13 = new Node() { Val = 6 };

            var a21 = new Node() { Val = 7 };
            var a22 = new Node() { Val = 8 };

            a1.Children.AddRange(new Node[] { a11, a12, a13 });
            a2.Children.AddRange(new Node[] { a21, a22 });

            root.Children.AddRange(new Node[] { a1, a2 });

            Console.WriteLine(root.DescendantsSum);
            Console.WriteLine(root.TreeSum);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(a1.DescendantsSum);
            Console.WriteLine(a1.TreeSum);

        }
    }


    class Node
    {
        public int Val { get; set; }

        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sum of values in descendant nodes
        /// </summary>   
        public int DescendantsSum
        {
            get
            {
                return TreeSum - Val;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sum of values in tree whose root is this node
        /// </summary>
        public int TreeSum
        {
            get
            {
                return GetTreeSum(this); 
            }
        }


        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }



        private int GetTreeSum(Node node)
        {
            int result = 0;

            if (node.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                result += node.Val;
                node.Children.ForEach(c => { result += GetTreeSum(c); });
            }
            else
                result += node.Val;

            return result;
        }
    }
```